# Getting checksum of 'latest' artifact

Tags: powershell, artifactory

I want to pull the latest package from Artifactory, but only if it hasn't already been downloaded.

I'm using the generic repo, and I'm downloading the latest package with PowerShell e.g.

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://myArtifactoryUrl/artifactory/myrepo/folder/package/package-[RELEASE].zip" -Method Get -OutFile "C:\temp\package.zip" -Headers $Header
```

So I want to get the checksum of the 'latest' file and compare it to the local one, without downloading anything. If it differs, I'll download it.

My issue is that I can't see (in the Artifactory API) how to get the checksum of the latest file in a repo, only on a specific file?

The package is potentially very large, so I want to avoid unnecessary downloads.

I notice the Artifactory CLI does this checksum compare for you, but it's a bit of a faff using it (this is in the cloud, corporate network, for a puppet module on windows). I'd rather do this in PS

Any steers would be much appreciated. I don't think this should be particularly difficult, but perhaps this isn't the best approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you can do is send a HEAD request, that way you are not actually downloading the file. After getting the file name in the response, you can query Artifactory for the checksum and compare it. 
Also, when running a search for the latest artifact, you get the following headers back:

Server: Artifactory/4.13.0

X-Artifactory-Id: 27e2ee2e1ade8482:-7fa4c4b5:15ad2daab10:-8000

Last-Modified: Wed, 15 Mar 2017 16:44:59 GMT

ETag: 10d759d4a8a297bf5e28a6fc7eaf4b969d78a098

**X-Checksum-Sha1: 10d759d4a8a297bf5e28a6fc7eaf4b969d78a098**

Accept-Ranges: bytes

X-Checksum-Md5: e30227b29222ec6f007524d91829878a

X-Artifactory-Filename: multi2-3.5-20170315.164450-2.jar

Content-Disposition: attachment;

filename="multi2-3.5-20170315.164450-2.jar";

filename*=UTF-8''multi2-3.5-20170315.164450-2.jar

Content-Type: application/java-archive

Content-Length: 1022

Date: Wed, 15 Mar 2017 16:45:26 GMT

Does that help?

Comment: Bingo, thanks! Using the Head method along with switching to Invoke-WebRequest returns the checksums I've been looking for :)

Comment: what is s `HEAD` request? and what does it look like?

Comment: @LeiYang Google: 
1. The HEAD method is identical to GET except that the server MUST NOT return a message-body in the response. The metainformation contained in the HTTP headers in response to a HEAD request SHOULD be identical to the information sent in response to a GET request. This method can be used for obtaining metainformation about the entity implied by the request without transferring the entity-body itself. This method is often used for testing hypertext links for validity, accessibility, and recent modification.

2. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/HEAD